# Log Solutions In Table

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I need help please.I created a calculator and wondering how i can make it to show the result both on the textbox and create a log on a column.
    One for the question and another column for the answer./*
   [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jrsr/2kxez0rz/)

```
<input type="button" value="=" 

onClick="document.calculator.ans.value=eval

(document.calculator.ans.value); addlog();" />
</form> 
<br>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>

  </tr>



<script>

function addlog()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "Question";
    cell2.innerHTML = "solution";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem, your table seems to be broken. Complete the table tag perhaps like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Question</th>
        <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Next you could change from "onLoad" to "No wrap - (inhead)"

Then define the function like this with a global variable on top - question:

```
var question;
function addlog () {

    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

    cell1.innerHTML = question;

    cell2.innerHTML = document.calculator.ans.value;

}
```

Finally in your calling method set the question and call addlog:

```
<input type="button" value="=" onclick="
question = document.calculator.ans.value;document.calculator.ans.value=eval(document.calculator.ans.value); addlog();" />
```

Here is a JSFiddle that seems to run fine [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45p4d8gq/)

Comment: Thank you for the help, i will take note of that, i'm just starting out and trying to learn on my own. thanks again you guys rock!

Answer (score 0):

When I check the javascript console in your fiddle, it tells me `addlog() is not defined`.  This is because it is defined in an `onLoad` event, which means it is defined within another function and therefore will not be visible to your window-level elements.  Look for information on lexical closures to understand why.

The solution is simple: explicitly define your function as part of the window object:

```
window.addlog = function() {
    //the same code here
}
```

There are other solutions, but this is a "best practice".  In fact, all global variables should be explicit to make debugging easier.  I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kxez0rz/5/) that will address the rest of your question.  I didn't add it to my answer because I didn't think it would be helpful to the community at large.